# Integrated Authentication From VM-based AD into Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, windows-authentication

I'm looking for some guidance on an issue I'm trying to solve. Right now, our web.config connection string contains plain-text password and username. Due to compliance reasons, we must remove those plain-text credentials and substitute them with integrated authentication. In the past, this was done by subbing the plain-text creds with 'trusted_connection=yes'.

Further clarification on our setup - We're in the process of migrating to Azure. The setup looks like this: we have a pair of VM's running Active Directory, our web VM is running standard IIS, and that's talking to Azure SQL DB. Unfortunately, we cannot move to Azure AD, as we have other requirements that require that to remain. Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

tl;dr - How can we get plain-text credentials out of the web.config file in an environment that has VM-based AD and Azure SQL DB.

- Web.config file is on windows server 2016 running IIS
- AD is on pair of 2016 VMs
- Azure SQL DB is PaaS

`Web.config`:

```
<add key="Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />

<add key="Persist Security Info=False;trusted_connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can we get plain-text credentials out of the web.config file in an environment that has VM-based AD and Azure SQL DB.

The *right* way to do this in Azure is to provision a [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) for your VM, and use that identity acquire an Access Token for SQL Server.  You can follow the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql).

In this scenario your connection string doesn't need any security information.  Just something like:

```
"Data Source = someInstance.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog = someDatabase;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Alternatively, you can use the MSI to access the Azure Key Vault and retrieve the SQL Auth credentials to connect, instead of storing them in your Config File, per the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad).

You can also *try* to configure your App Pool to run under a domain account configured for [Seamless Signon with AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-how-it-works), just like *you* should be accessing Azure SQL Database when logged into a Domain-joined workstation.  But there's a lot of potential complexity in that path.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing an answer, David! I did, in fact, read through that tutorial, and i've actually configured both the VM, and the DB to accept Managed Identities. I can also connect to the DB from the VM using an access token, but the problem lies in the fact that we cannot get the web.config to a point where it's seamlessly authenticating using the ID that i've configured.  In other words, is it possible to use the MSI method to seamlessly authenticate within the web.config file?

Comment: Continuation of above - Since we're migrating into Azure, we already have all of our code in place for the websites.  Once the MSI is setup, I'm lost on what needs to change on the application pool within IIS and how the connection string should change within our web.config file to be able to authenticate in an integrated fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to use the access token without changing code.  Anyplace you call SqlConnection.Open(), you first must set the SqlConnection.AccessToken property.

Comment: Thanks again, David.  Would you happen to know of a good reference I can follow to understand the changes that would be needed to the web.config if I am going to use the access token method?

Comment: I think I'm getting close, but still having problems with the webpage communicating to the DB.  I put in the connection string you provided and added the values specific to my env, but communication to the backend DB is failing.  I'm getting ```Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.``` Is there something that needs to change on the Application Pool as well?

Comment: To use an MSI you must write code to retrieve the AccessToken and set it on the SqlConnection.  There's no way to do this with only a configuration file change.